# L1(R) subpace of finite radon measures M(R)

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a paper and want to understand the following proposition.
Let $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$, then $\|f\|_M = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| dx = \|f\|_{L_1}$,
with

$\| w\|_M := \sup\limits_{\phi \in C_0(\mathbb{R}), \| \phi \|_\infty = 1} <w, \phi> =\sup\limits_{\phi \in C_0(\mathbb{R}), \| \phi \|_\infty = 1} \int_{\mathbb{R}}w(x)\phi(x) dx $.

Does anyone have any suggentions why this holds?

Comment: @geetha290krm Density in $L^1$ wont help, one would have to replace $C_0$ by $L^\infty$ when taking the supremum. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @lazardsk, one idea would be: write the integral $\int_\mathbb R|w| = \int w\cdot sign(w)$, approximate $sign(w)$ by continuous functions (i.e. mollification), show convergence of the integrals (dominated convergence)